# avoid fragment list data duplicating on recyclerView

Tags: android

I had some fragments switch on one activity.

I found a issue is that when i turn back the fragment , it will show duplicate data.

I try to clear the arrayList data to solve it.

But i want to know more smart way.

Is any possible to avoid this issue for duplicate data ?

My fragment code:

```
public class Vaccine extends Fragment {

    private List<VaccineItem> vaccineList = new ArrayList<>();
    private VaccineAdapter vaccineAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerVaccine;

    public Vaccine() {
    }

    public static Vaccine newInstance() {
        return new Vaccine();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vaccine_fragment_, container, false);

        recyclerVaccine = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerVaccine);
        recyclerVaccine.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        vaccineList.clear();// i use it to slove the problem.--------------
        testData();
        vaccineAdapter = new VaccineAdapter(getActivity(), vaccineList);
        recyclerVaccine.setAdapter(vaccineAdapter);
        vaccineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }
    private void testData(){
        VaccineItem vaccineItem=new VaccineItem("Data1");
        vaccineList.add(vaccineItem);
        vaccineItem=new VaccineItem("Data2");
        vaccineList.add(vaccineItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with this

```
View view; // declare this globally

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(view == null){ // initialize if view is null
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vaccine_fragment_, container, false);

    recyclerVaccine = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerVaccine);
    recyclerVaccine.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    vaccineList.clear();// i use it to slove the problem.--------------
    testData();
    vaccineAdapter = new VaccineAdapter(getActivity(), vaccineList);
    recyclerVaccine.setAdapter(vaccineAdapter);
    vaccineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: yap , it' work !  do you usually use this way to avoid the issue like me?

Comment: @徐博俊, yes,  I think this is best idea. if we have already view initialized.. why should we go for inflate second time if there is no changes in UI

Comment: `vaccineList.clear()` worked like charm thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call testData() in your constructor, not in onCreateView.

Comment: Is not the same meaning ? when i resume the fragment , it's still be call

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting duplicate data is because you are calling testData() when fragment view is created. This adds same items everytime your fragment is recreated. There is nothing wrong with clearing the list though.

Comment: yap , i just thought it will be a more correct approach.

Comment: this is just a test, in a real situation you would refresh your data at this point. by either fetching it from db or api and you'd need to clear or rewrite your old data anyway.

Comment: yes , you are right , i learn the point , thanks @Andrej Jurkin